# how to create alias folder on apache 2

Tags: php, apache2, virtual, mod-alias

I want to create an alias to a folder in Apache2(with centos 6 and PHP5.4). My idea is to migrate a project from one server to another.

Example:

**htaccess:**

```
SetAlias /home/before.com/ /home/after.com/
```

**PHP**

```
include( '/home/before.com/header.php' );//include header from "/home/after.com/"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's the wrong way to do it. See the docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

You cannot set aliases in .htaccess, either.